# Jest Mock a Class Method that return promise

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

i am having a react component that gets data on page load.

example.component.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { Apis } from '../misc/apis';

function App() {
  const apis= new Apis();
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let mounted = true;
    apis.getList()
      .then(items => {
        if(mounted) {
          setList(items)
        }
      })
    return () => mounted = false;
  }, [])

  return(
    <div className="wrapper">
     <h1>My Grocery List</h1>
     <ul>
       {list.map(item => <li key={item.item}>{item.item}</li>)}
     </ul>
   </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

apis.js

```
  export class Apis{
   constructor(){
     console.log(constructor called)
   }
   getList: () => {
     promise.resolve([{"item":"1"},{"item":"2"}]) //sample api response 
   }
  }
```

test file example component.test.js

```
jest.mock('../misc/apis',()=>{
getList: jest.fn(()=> Promise.resolve([{"item":"3"},{"item":"4"}]))
})
```

when i try to mock as per above, i am getting Apis is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience when using `jest` with `react` or `vue` - mocking out instance variables is a little bit more tricky.

Your tests will work if you write them as follows:

```
it('test', () => {
  jest.spyOn(Apis.prototype, "getList").mockResolvedValue([{"item":"3"},{"item":"4"}]);
  // other logic; e.g: render(<App />);
})
```